# Microsoft UITesting Automation Engine Information

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, coded-ui-tests

I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting to hand-code automated tests for a Silverlight web application.  I am running into an inconsistent failure problem, and I need to understand what visual studio is doing when it runs a test.

**Where can I find detailed technical information on the testing framework/engine in Visual Studio?**  Or to state more specifically, I am looking for information on what is going on 'behind the scenes' when I run a test.

Comment: What's your inconsistent failure?  It's likely that someone else here will have seen it too, if it's a problem with the testing framework.

Comment: It is when the automation engine cannot find the PageTemplate (one of 2 base controls used to identify the Silverlight window).  It happens inconsistently, and while the error says it is the PageTemplate, my tests have led me to believe it is something else going on behind the scenes (I removed the page template identifier and just used the alternate window identifier (the SL object itself) and I still received an inconsistent failure.  I do not remember what this error was, but it was unhelpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify any specific information that you are looking for, I'll link you to a couple of "portal" pages that I tend to have good luck with when searching for Coded UI information.

The first one is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/12/10/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx, it's also got some links to some blogs of Microsoft employees who specialize in the Coded UI testing framework.

The second one is a bit smaller, but the links are a bit more organized: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726(VS.100).aspx.

I hope you find something useful on one of these.